# How do I properly set ios flags for stream manipulation?

Tags: c++, iomanip

I typed up a basic example in C++ in which I try to print a number to screen as hexadecimal below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    unsigned number {314};

    auto flags {std::ios::showbase | std::ios::hex};
    std::cout.setf(flags);

    // expected output: 0x13A
    std::cout << number << std::endl;

    std::cout.unsetf(flags);

   // expected output: 314
   std::cout << number << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

However, the number is never displayed in hexadecimal format. Am I setting the flags properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set `hex` you need to clear all the `basefield`s. If you don't do it, then both the `hex` and `dec` flags are both set. While I am not sure what should happen if multiple flags for the same mask are set, your implementation chooses to use `dec`, when both `hex` and `dec` flags are set.

You want:

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield);
std::cout.setf(std::ios::showbase);
```

and then clear with

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios::dec, std::ios::basefield);
std::cout.unsetf(std::ios::showbase);
```

Comment: How can I store all my flags in a variable such as `flags` so that I can easily `setf` and `unsetf`. Furthermore, why was it necessary to set 2 of the flags on one line and the `std::ios::showbase` flag on the next?

Comment: Well, with `std::ios_base::flags()`, just `auto f = std::cout.flags()`. And then restore with `std::cout.flags(f)`. Och, it's not necessary, you can do `cout.setf(hex | showbase, basefield)`, but I don't see how to mix `setf` and `unsetf`. (Probably something along `cout.flags(cout.flags() & ~showbase & ~basefield | hex)` if I didn't made errors.)

Comment: @KamilCuk what's that comma ',` signifies rather than bitwise operator `|`  between two flag manipulators.

Comment: @AbhishekMane I do not understand. Comma and `|` are not interchangeable. I believe you should research what are function overloads in C++ and learn about two  [setf overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf).

Comment: okay I will check it can you give another article or link where it explained clearly. cppreference site is very diffcult to understand.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am asking that the Question asked by user uses `|` between two flag manipulators but in answer you use `,` between two flag manipulators. I  checked `|` it 
sets both manipulators but `,` not works.